# Error while loading shared libraries: libicuuc.so.59: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: pacman, arch-arm

After update with `pacman -Syuq`:

```
# pacman -Sc

pacman: error while loading shared libraries: libicuuc.so.59: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

# find / -name libicuuc.so.* 2>/dev/null
/usr/lib/libicuuc.so.60.1
/usr/lib/libicuuc.so.60
```

Arch Linux in a Pi version 1:

```
# uname -an
4.9.62-1-ARCH #1 SMP Fri Nov 17 13:42:55 UTC 2017 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Same problem here, appeared today. For me libicuuc.so.59. I have to go through command line to boot and many programs do not work anymore

Comment: Also missing libicui18n.so.59 probably related

Comment: I actually solved my problem with pacman -Sc followed by pacman -Syuu

Answer (score 30):

Previously proposed solutions were not relevant or did not work for me. For some reason upgrading the `icu` package from 59.1-2 to 60.1-1 made linkage break and many programs (including pacman) failed with this error after. No interrupted pacman on my side.

If you still have the previous package in your cache, you can try this, which worked for me:

1. Locate cached version of package (for example, mine was `/var/cache/pacman/pkg/icu-59.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`).
2. Extract it: `mkdir -p ~/pkg/tmp && tar xJvf /var/cache/pacman/pkg/icu-59.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz -C ~/pkg/tmp`
3. Copy libs to your lib folder: `sudo cp ~/pkg/tmp/usr/lib/libicu*.59 /usr/lib/`
4. Proceed with update: `sudo pacman -Syu`
5. You can now remove the files you just extracted.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. But how should I safe remove copied libicu*.59 files? `rm /usr/lib/libicu*.59` ?

Comment: This worked for me as well. Thanks, have an upvote.

Comment: I had the same problem with icu 68, and your solution worked just fine. thanks man!

Comment: Thanks, you saved my life! Now I know the method of dealing with broken shared libraries.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable to load the icu libraries from a different location. In this way, you can avoid any copies to /usr/lib:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/pkg/tmp
$ tar xJvf /var/cache/pacman/pkg/icu-59.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz -C ~/pkg/tmp
$ su
# LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`/pkg/tmp pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/icu-59.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

Comment: It was `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\`pwd\`/pkg/tmp/usr/lib` in my case.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have an executable that needs that particular version of the library (as it happened in my case), there is an [aur package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/icu59/) for that specific version.

Answer (score 1):

I researched the problem and found about the `/var/log/pacman.log`. I read the log and found that the problem was:

```
...
[2017-11-28 04:34] [ALPM] upgraded libmariadbclient (10.1.28-1 -> 10.1.29-1)
[2017-11-28 04:34] [ALPM] transaction interrupted
```

The update was interrupted, hence the linkage problem.

I then downloaded the firmware from [here](http://hu.mirror.archlinuxarm.org/os/ArchLinuxARM-rpi-latest.tar.gz). I extracted the missing library:

```
$ gunzip ArchLinuxARM-rpi-latest.tar.gz
$ tar -tf ArchLinuxARM-rpi-latest.tar |grep libicuuc.so.59
./usr/lib/libicuuc.so.59.1
./usr/lib/libicuuc.so.59
$ tar -xf ArchLinuxARM-rpi-latest.tar ./usr/lib/libicuuc.so.59.1
$ tar -xf ArchLinuxARM-rpi-latest.tar ./usr/lib/libicuuc.so.59
```

`libicuuc.so.59` was a symlink to `libicuuc.so.59.1`, so I moved `libicuuc.so.59.1` to `/usr/lib/libicuuc.so.59`.

Running `pacman` I got the error that `libicudata.so.59` was missing. I extracted the missing library to `/usr/lib` and `pacman` was working :).

I then updated the system with `pacman -Syuq` and checked with `ldd /usr/bin/pacman` that all libraries were present. I moved the v59 libraries from `/usr/lib` and checked that `pacman` was working.

Reboot with fingers crossed... successfully!!!

`pacman -Sc` and go to bed with a smile :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem with pacman -Sc followed by pacman -Syyu
Not sure why it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your system lib32-icu is not installed. Just install lib32-icu from pacman and all problem will be solved.

```
sudo pacman -S lib32-icu
```

Answer (score 1):

Download (HTTP): https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-70-1/icu4c-70_1-src.tgz.  
Then

```
tar -xf icu4c-70_1-src.tgz &&
cd icu4c-70_1-src/source &&
./configure --prefix=/usr &&
make &&
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the help of the following link;
[here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=220224)

According to this article downgrading is a bad idea and what you should probably do is rebuild the package that uses the above missing dependancy. Downgrading may affect multiple packages.

Answer (score 0):

**`/usr/lib/chromium/chromium: error while loading shared libraries: libicuuc.so.65: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`**

`# ln -s /usr/lib/libicuuc.so.67.1  /usr/lib/libicuuc.so.65`

Quick and dirty.